# Using jQuery to change selected item on Menu bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following set of html defining a menu bar:

```
<ul id="menu-bar">
    <li class="active"><a href="/" id="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Club/" id="club">Club Quarter</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Match/" id="match">Match Quarter</a></li>
    <li><a href="/History/" id="history">History Quarter</a></li>
</ul>
```

The menu bar has a red background with the active item's background set to blue.

I have the following piece of jQuery which removes the active class of the current selected item and places it on the new item that has just been clicked.

```
$('#menu-bar > li').click(function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

When I single click a new item, a large proportion of the time, the background of the current item changes to red and the background of the selected item changes to blue. Then it immediately reverts back to the status quo. Other times nothing happens although the click has been recognised because the page changes correctly.

When I double click a new item. The change happens as I expected, although if I check the HTML, more often than not, "class=active" is still attached to the default first item, even though its background is now red and the clicked item is blue.

- Should a single click give me the effect I want or am I missing
  something?
- On a double click, how can the default item now be red even though it is still
  set as the active class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're clicking the list element, you're really clicking the anchor, which in turn redirects to another page, where all your javascript is reset and starts again at scratch ?

You simply can not set a class dynamically, redirect, and then expect the class to still be added to the element. Everything is lost when you redirect. You have to hardcode the active menu item on each page, or use a persistent storage like cookies, localStorage or the server to keep the state of the page on reloads.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I've swapped the main menubar off the Header/Footer container onto each loaded page and set the chosen element individually. It means the main menubar is repeated on each page but at least it works the way I was expecting it to.